# Pointer loses its value when called in different thread

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pthreads, dump

I had implemented a queue system to transfer data from one thread to my mains loop, im attaching that code here

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pthread.h"

#define MAX_QUEUE_SIZE      (100)
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE       (10000)

// A structure to represent a queue
struct Queue {
    unsigned int front, rear, size;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int ele_size;
    char* array;
};

//queue lock
pthread_mutex_t qlock;

// function to create a queue of given capacity.
// It initializes size of queue as 0
struct Queue* createQueue(unsigned int capacity, unsigned int ele_size)
{
    struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));

    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->front = queue->size = 0;
    queue->rear = capacity - 1;
    queue->ele_size = ele_size;

    queue->array = (char*)malloc(queue->capacity * ele_size);
    if(queue->array == NULL)
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\n Fail to allocate memory..!!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    }

    memset(queue->array, 0, (queue->capacity * sizeof(ele_size)));

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&qlock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n Fail to init mutex\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    return queue;
}

// Queue is full when size becomes equal to the capacity
int isFull(struct Queue* queue)
{
    return (queue->size == queue->capacity);
}

// Queue is empty when size is 0
int isEmpty(struct Queue* queue)
{
    return (queue->size == 0);
}

// Function to know number of arrays in queue
int no_elements(struct Queue* queue)
{
    unsigned int size = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);

    size = queue->size;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);

    return size;
}
void* getnode(struct Queue* queue)
{
    char *node = malloc(queue->ele_size);
    return node;
}
void freenode(char *node)
{
    if(node != NULL)
        free(node);
}
// Function to add an item to the queue.
void enqueue(struct Queue* queue, void *data, unsigned int size)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);

    if (isFull(queue))
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
        return;
    }

    queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1) % queue->capacity;
    //printf(" size is  %d index is %d\n",(queue->rear * queue->ele_size),queue->rear);
    //fflush(stdout);

    memmove(&(queue->array[queue->rear * queue->ele_size]), data, size);


    queue->size = queue->size + 1;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);

    return;
}

// Function to remove an item from queue.
// It changes front and size
void dequeue(struct Queue* queue, void* data, unsigned int size)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);

    if (isEmpty(queue))
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
        return;
    }

    if(data == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Invalid args..!!\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);
        return;
    }

    memcpy(data, &(queue->array[queue->front * queue->ele_size]), size);

    queue->front = (queue->front + 1) % queue->capacity;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);

    return;
}

void deleteQueue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qlock);

    if(queue->array != NULL)
        free(queue->array);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qlock);

}
```

I have a function which deques data from the queue and enqueue is happening in a different pthread

the function for dequeue is

```
    SenderData* Dequeue_elements_rec(struct Queue*structqueuehandle)
{
    char *deq_node = getnode(structqueuehandle);
    dequeue(structqueuehandle, deq_node, (sizeof(SenderData) + 10000));
    SenderData *data2 = (SenderData*)malloc(sizeof(SenderData));
    memcpy(data2, deq_node, sizeof(SenderData));
    data2->Data = malloc(data2->DataSize);
    memcpy(data2->Data, deq_node + sizeof(SenderData), data2->DataSize);
    printf("cmd: %d size: %d\n", data2->CommandCode, data2->DataSize);
    SenderData *test_ptr = (SenderData*)data2;
    printf("cmd code from msg_ptr is %d\n",test_ptr->DataSize);
    printf("cmd code from msg_ptr is %d\n",test_ptr->CommandCode);
    int *testi = (int*)data2->Data;
    printf("dq---%d %d %d  data size: %d\n", testi[0], testi[1], testi[209], data2->DataSize);
    fflush(stdout);
    freenode(deq_node);

    return test_ptr;

}
```

sender data is defined like

```
    typedef struct SenderData {
    unsigned int CommandCode;
    unsigned int DataSize;
    void *Data;
    //unsigned char DestID;   **
} SenderData;
```

My main code is here

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    config_rec_engine();
    usleep(1000*1000);

    while(1)
    {


        if(no_elements(rec_queue_hndl)>0)
        {
            printf("inside deq \n");

            SenderData *temp=Dequeue_elements_rec(rec_queue_hndl);
            //printf("Code is %d\n",temp->CommandCode);

            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else
        {

            usleep(1000*1000);
        }

    }
    deleteQueue(rec_queue_hndl);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, when i try to print the dequeued data from my main thread, i get error and its like segmentation fault, but when i try to print the same data from my dequeue function, im getting data correctly. Im just passing received pointer as the return of the function.

This is the printf from the dequeued data element called data2 which is coming correctly

```
data from  from data2 cmd code is  : 240 size: 840
```

this is the printf from the pointer which is assigned by the statement

SenderData *test_ptr = (SenderData*)data2;

here also cdata is correct , but when i print from the pointer in mains, its not working

```
    Size from msg_ptr is 840
    cmd code from msg_ptr is 240
    dq---207 1 209  data size: 840
```

.......................console..............................

```
 >>>>>>REC_Engine_Started<<<<<<<
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq 
data from  from data2 cmd code is  : 240 size: 840
Size from msg_ptr is 840
cmd code from msg_ptr is 240
dq---207 1 209  data size: 840
      0 [main] udpexx1 822 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to udpexx1.exe.stackdump
```

this is where im creating my queue

```
    void config_rec_engine(void)
{
    skt=CSPL__CreateSocket();
    CSPL_re_use(skt);
    Bindtoport(skt,65533);
    Add_mul_cast_member(skt,"192.168.1.11","225.1.1.2");
    //// Queue ////////
    rec_queue_hndl = createQueue(1000, (sizeof(SenderData) + 10000) );
    rec_thread1_ret = pthread_create(&rec_thread_1, NULL, Receiver_thread,(void*) rec_message1);
    //pthread_join(Send_thread_1, NULL);



}
```

as part of debugging, i make data2 as global and tried to get data in my mains, this works without any problem

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    config_rec_engine();
    usleep(1000*1000);

    while(1)
    {


        if(no_elements(rec_queue_hndl)>0)
        {
            printf("inside deq \n");

            SenderData *temp=Dequeue_elements_rec(rec_queue_hndl);
            printf("print from mains code  is %d\n",data2->CommandCode);

            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else
        {

            usleep(1000*1000);
        }

    }
    deleteQueue(rec_queue_hndl);

    return 0;
}
```

and my console print is .....................

```
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq 
data from  from data2 cmd code is  : 1291 size: 840
Size from msg_ptr is 840
cmd code from msg_ptr is 1291
dq---1258 1 209  data size: 840
print from mains code  is 1291
```

Expected Data is , this is in a while loop and continuously sends over udp socket

```
        cont[0]++;
        cont[1] = 1;
        cont[209] = 209;
   

        data.CommandCode=33+cont[0];
        data.DataSize=sizeof(cont);
        data.Data=cont;

        Enqueue_elements(queue_hndl, &data);
```

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ikweBo0_HKU6fvZxKPlXNopSnV7EoJgW?usp=sharing)

Comment: Im editing my code to show the create queue section, im creating quew with 10000 as size

Comment: Better, but we still need to see the `Receiver_thread` function and the setup/initialization of `rec_message1`. Ideally, enough to download and compile cleanly and be [somewhat] runnable. The `CSPL_*` is non-standard [to me, at least], so I've nop'ed it in the copy I already have. We'd like to be able to run the program _without_ actually having to connect to a multicast group. So, what is representative data that causes the fault?

Comment: @CraigEstey  this is the data that I'm sending, sorry i dono how to format in this comment 

cont[0]++;
  cont[1] = 1;
  cont[209] = 209;



  data.CommandCode=33+cont[0];
  data.DataSize=sizeof(cont);
  data.Data=cont;

  Enqueue_elements(queue_hndl, &data);

Comment: @CraigEstey i have updated my question with expected data

Comment: Okay, I presume that is the body of `Receiver_thread`??? What is [the definition of] `cont` and `data`? But, this also introduces a call to `Enqueue_elements` [which we don't have]. So far, I'm counting about 290 lines of source code. That's small enough that you could [and should] post _all_ the code in a _single_ code block at the bottom. It should compile cleanly

Comment: @CraigEstey For easy access i have given t he link for my code  i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* It's difficult to be sure without seeing your entire code, but ...

In `Dequeue_elements_rec`, we have:

```
char *deq_node = getnode(structqueuehandle);

dequeue(structqueuehandle, deq_node, (sizeof(SenderData) + 10000));
```

`getnode` does a `malloc` with length `queue->ele_size`. Without more code, we don't really know *what* that length is. So, I assume it's something small (e.g.) `sizeof(SenderData)`, so 30 [or so] bytes.

When we call `dequeue`, the third arg is: `(sizeof(SenderData) + 10000)`, so the length passed is ~10000 bytes.

In `dequeue`, we have:

```
memcpy(data, &(queue->array[queue->front * queue->ele_size]), size);
```

So, `data` points to a small area. And, we're copying from `queue->array`.

But, the value of `size` is at least 10000 bytes. So, unless `ele_size` is at least 10000 bytes when `createQueue` is called [somewhere earlier], this `memcpy` will segfault either writing to `data` or trying to fetch from the source argument.

---

**UPDATE:**

> For easy access i have given t he link for my code i have updated my question – RHKP

Okay, I downloaded the `.zip` files from your Google Drive, unzipped them.

I had to do some cleanup to make it compile on my system under Linux.
I had to add some function prototypes to some `.h` files. And, I had to move the `struct Queue` definition from `my_queue.c` into `my_queue.h`. And, I had to remove the "guard" `#ifndef` from `my_queue.c` because it conflicted with the one in `my_queue.h`

Also, I was having trouble with the build structure, so I ignored all the complex `gcc` command line options and just built the program(s) manually.

Note that I had to adjust the unicast addresses (e.g. `192.168.x.y` doesn't play too well in my environment). I adjusted that to a `10.x.y.z` address here, but that didn't work either. I had to settle for `127.x.y.z`.

When I was last using multicast, I used `239.x.y.z` which is "organization local" [vs. "reserved"]. I switched to that at first.

After I did all that, I ran each program in a separate terminal window.

Both programs ran without error!

So, I can only wonder if some `.o` files on your setup were *not* rebuilt (e.g. I'd do a `make clean`).

Or, this is some `cygwin` specific issue. I'd suggest that you try this on a linux machine to see. You could also try building this with `mingw`. Or, install `WSL2` and run (e.g.) `ubuntu` as a virtual machine [Or, some other hypervisor like `virtualbox`, `xen`, `vmware`, etc].

Here is the output of the `Host` program:

```
UNI_ADDRESS=127.0.0.11
MCAST_ADDRESS=225.1.1.2
>>>>>>REC_Engine_Started<<<<<<<
>>>>>>Sender_Engine_Started<<<<<<<
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq
print from mains code  is 34
dqffff---1 1 209  data size: 840
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq
print from mains code  is 35
dqffff---2 1 209  data size: 840
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq
print from mains code  is 36
dqffff---3 1 209  data size: 840
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq
print from mains code  is 37
dqffff---4 1 209  data size: 840
malloced************
add single data
Sending Ack
inside deq
print from mains code  is 38
dqffff---5 1 209  data size: 840
```

Here is the output of the `receiver` program:

```
UNI_ADDRESS=127.0.0.10
MCAST_ADDRESS=225.1.1.2
>>>>>>Sender_Engine_Started<<<<<<<
CMD Code 34---Size 840Sending- 209
data flag 0
single packet data sent
CMD Code 35---Size 840Sending- 209
data flag 0
single packet data sent
CMD Code 36---Size 840Sending- 209
data flag 0
single packet data sent
CMD Code 37---Size 840Sending- 209
data flag 0
single packet data sent
CMD Code 38---Size 840Sending- 209
data flag 0
single packet data sent
```

Here is the `diff -ru` output for the changes I made:

```
diff -ru unzip/Host/Debug/src/subdir.mk fixed/Host/Debug/src/subdir.mk
--- unzip/Host/Debug/src/subdir.mk  2021-06-01 14:31:27.901262121 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/Debug/src/subdir.mk  2021-06-01 13:42:58.408494344 -0400
@@ -13,11 +13,15 @@
 ./src/udpexx1.d

+SADIR := $(HOME)/tmp/queue/Host/SocketAPI
+ILIST += -I$(SADIR)
+VPATH := $(SADIR)
+
 # Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
 src/%.o: ../src/%.c src/subdir.mk
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler'
-   gcc -I"C:\cygwin64\bin" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@" "$<"
+   gcc $(ILIST) -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

diff -ru unzip/Host/SocketAPI/Global_dat.h fixed/Host/SocketAPI/Global_dat.h
--- unzip/Host/SocketAPI/Global_dat.h   2021-06-01 14:31:27.933261450 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/SocketAPI/Global_dat.h   2021-06-01 17:01:59.775120694 -0400
@@ -3,6 +3,20 @@

 //HSFC UDP Data Packet definition

+//Add_mul_cast_member(skt,"192.168.1.11","225.1.1.2");
+#if UNI_ORIG == 1
+#define UNI_ADDRESS        "192.168.1.11"
+#elif UNI_ORIG == 2
+#define UNI_ADDRESS        "10.0.0.96"
+#else
+#define UNI_ADDRESS        "127.0.0.11"
+#endif
+#ifdef MCAST_ORIG
+#define MCAST_ADDRESS  "225.1.1.2"
+#else
+#define MCAST_ADDRESS  "239.1.1.2"
+#endif
+
 typedef struct HSFC_UDP_Packet {
    unsigned short Year;          // year
    unsigned char  Month;         // months
diff -ru unzip/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.c fixed/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.c
--- unzip/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.c 2021-06-01 20:13:36.000000000 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.c 2021-06-01 13:53:01.173779495 -0400
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-#ifndef MY_QUEUE_H   // Include guard
-#define MY_QUEUE_H
+//#ifndef MY_QUEUE_H   // Include guard
+//#define MY_QUEUE_H

 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
@@ -7,21 +7,16 @@
 #include <string.h>
 #include "pthread.h"

+#include <my_queue.h>
+
 #define    MAX_QUEUE_SIZE      (100)
 #define MAX_DATA_SIZE      (10000)

-// A structure to represent a queue
-struct Queue {
-   unsigned int front, rear, size;
-   unsigned int capacity;
-   unsigned int ele_size;
-   char* array;
-};
-
 //queue lock
 pthread_mutex_t qlock;

-int no_elements(struct Queue* queue);
+//int no_elements(struct Queue* queue);
+
 // function to create a queue of given capacity.
 // It initializes size of queue as 0
 struct Queue* createQueue(unsigned int capacity, unsigned int ele_size)
@@ -152,4 +147,4 @@

 }

-#endif
+//#endif
diff -ru unzip/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.h fixed/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.h
--- unzip/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.h 2021-06-01 20:14:00.000000000 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/SocketAPI/my_queue.h 2021-06-01 13:02:31.610344349 -0400
@@ -10,6 +10,15 @@
 #define    MAX_QUEUE_SIZE      (100)
 #define MAX_DATA_SIZE      (10000)

+// A structure to represent a queue
+struct Queue {
+   unsigned int front, rear, size;
+   unsigned int capacity;
+   unsigned int ele_size;
+   char* array;
+};
+
+int no_elements(struct Queue* queue);

 struct Queue* createQueue(unsigned int capacity, unsigned int ele_size);
 void deleteQueue(struct Queue* queue);
diff -ru unzip/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.c fixed/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.c
--- unzip/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.c 2021-06-01 14:31:27.944261219 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.c 2021-06-01 16:55:36.010174477 -0400
@@ -240,19 +240,24 @@

    return 0;
 }
+
 void config_rec_engine(void)
 {
+   printf("UNI_ADDRESS=%s\n",UNI_ADDRESS);
+   printf("MCAST_ADDRESS=%s\n",MCAST_ADDRESS);
    skt=CSPL__CreateSocket();
    CSPL_re_use(skt);
    Bindtoport(skt,65533);
+#if 0
    Add_mul_cast_member(skt,"192.168.1.11","225.1.1.2");
+#else
+   Add_mul_cast_member(skt,UNI_ADDRESS,MCAST_ADDRESS);
+#endif
    //// Queue ////////
    rec_queue_hndl = createQueue(1000, (sizeof(SenderData) + 5000) );
-   rec_thread1_ret = pthread_create(&rec_thread_1, NULL, Receiver_thread,(void*) rec_message1);
+   rec_thread1_ret = pthread_create(&rec_thread_1, NULL,
+       Receiver_thread,(void*) rec_message1);
    //pthread_join(Send_thread_1, NULL);
-
-
-
 }

 void *Receiver_thread(void *msg_ptr) // Sender Engine
@@ -293,10 +298,13 @@
 {
    char *deq_node = getnode(structqueuehandle);
    dequeue(structqueuehandle, deq_node, (sizeof(SenderData) + 5000));
+
    Received_data = (SenderData*)malloc(sizeof(SenderData));
    memcpy(Received_data, deq_node, sizeof(SenderData));
+
    Received_data->Data = malloc(Received_data->DataSize);
    memcpy(Received_data->Data, deq_node + sizeof(SenderData), Received_data->DataSize);
+
    //printf("data from  from data2 cmd code is  : %d size: %d\n", Received_data->CommandCode, Received_data->DataSize);
    test_ptr = (SenderData*)Received_data;
    //printf("Size from msg_ptr is %d\n",test_ptr->DataSize);
diff -ru unzip/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.h fixed/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.h
--- unzip/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.h 2021-06-01 14:31:27.946261177 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/SocketAPI/Receiver.h 2021-06-01 13:04:03.469411136 -0400
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
 //#include "Globals.h"

+SenderData* Dequeue_elements_rec(struct Queue*structqueuehandle);
 void Enqueue_elements_rec(struct Queue*structqueuehandle,SenderData* sending_packet);
 void CSPL_SOK_ERROR(int error_no);
 int CSPL__CreateSocket(void);
diff -ru unzip/Host/SocketAPI/sender.c fixed/Host/SocketAPI/sender.c
--- unzip/Host/SocketAPI/sender.c   2021-06-01 14:31:27.959260905 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/SocketAPI/sender.c   2021-06-01 14:11:39.174222789 -0400
@@ -293,7 +293,11 @@
     */
    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
+#if 0
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.1.1.2");
+#else
+   groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(MCAST_ADDRESS);
+#endif
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(65533);

    /*
@@ -315,7 +319,11 @@
     * The IP address specified must be associated with a local,
     * multicast-capable interface.
     */
+#if 0
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.10");
+#else
+   localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr(UNI_ADDRESS);
+#endif
    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF,
            (char *)&localInterface,
            sizeof(localInterface)) < 0) {
diff -ru unzip/Host/src/udpexx1.c fixed/Host/src/udpexx1.c
--- unzip/Host/src/udpexx1.c    2021-06-01 14:31:27.963260821 -0400
+++ fixed/Host/src/udpexx1.c    2021-06-01 13:06:01.845920123 -0400
@@ -1,4 +1,8 @@
+#if 0
 #include "my_queue.h"
+#else
+#include <my_queue.h>
+#endif
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>
@@ -9,6 +13,7 @@
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include "Global_dat.h"
 #include "Receiver.h"
+#include "sender.h"

 //#include "sender.c"

@@ -36,10 +41,16 @@
        {
            printf("inside deq \n");

+#if 0
            SenderData *temp=Dequeue_elements_rec(rec_queue_hndl);
+#else
+           SenderData *Received_data=Dequeue_elements_rec(rec_queue_hndl);
+#endif
+
            printf("print from mains code  is %d\n",Received_data->CommandCode);
            int *testi = (int*)Received_data->Data;
-           printf("dqffff---%d %d %d  data size: %d\n", testi[0], testi[1], testi[209], Received_data->DataSize);
+           printf("dqffff---%d %d %d  data size: %d\n",
+               testi[0], testi[1], testi[209], Received_data->DataSize);

            fflush(stdout);
        }
diff -ru unzip/receiver/api_include/Globals.h fixed/receiver/api_include/Globals.h
--- unzip/receiver/api_include/Globals.h    2021-06-01 14:31:28.006259918 -0400
+++ fixed/receiver/api_include/Globals.h    2021-06-01 17:02:05.188007105 -0400
@@ -1,4 +1,21 @@
 //HSFC UDP Data Packet definition
+#ifndef _api_globals_h_
+#define _api_globals_h_
+
+//Add_mul_cast_member(skt,"192.168.1.11","225.1.1.2");
+#if UNI_ORIG == 1
+#define UNI_ADDRESS        "192.168.1.10"
+#elif UNI_ORIG == 2
+#define UNI_ADDRESS        "10.0.0.96"
+#else
+#define UNI_ADDRESS        "127.0.0.10"
+#endif
+#ifdef MCAST_ORIG
+#define MCAST_ADDRESS  "225.1.1.2"
+#else
+#define MCAST_ADDRESS  "239.1.1.2"
+#endif
+
 typedef struct HSFC_UDP_Packet {
    unsigned short Year;          // year
    unsigned char  Month;         // months
@@ -44,3 +61,5 @@
    char Data[0];
    //unsigned char DestID;   **
 } SenderDataA;
+
+#endif
diff -ru unzip/receiver/api_include/sender.c fixed/receiver/api_include/sender.c
--- unzip/receiver/api_include/sender.c 2021-06-01 14:31:28.025259520 -0400
+++ fixed/receiver/api_include/sender.c 2021-06-01 16:54:20.968749441 -0400
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 #include<pthread.h>
-stop_nw_global=0;
+#include <Globals.h>
+
+//stop_nw_global=0;
 // related to data and packets
 HSFC_UDP_Packet headder;

@@ -246,6 +248,8 @@

 int start_sender_engine(void)
 {
+   printf("UNI_ADDRESS=%s\n",UNI_ADDRESS);
+   printf("MCAST_ADDRESS=%s\n",MCAST_ADDRESS);
    thread1_ret = pthread_create(&Send_thread_1, NULL, Sender_thread,(void*) message1);
    //pthread_join(Send_thread_1, NULL);
    //// Queue ////////
@@ -285,7 +289,11 @@
     */
    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
+#if 0
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.1.1.2");
+#else
+   groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(MCAST_ADDRESS);
+#endif
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(65533);

    /*
@@ -307,7 +315,11 @@
     * The IP address specified must be associated with a local,
     * multicast-capable interface.
     */
+#if 0
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.10");
+#else
+   localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr(UNI_ADDRESS);
+#endif
    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF,
            (char *)&localInterface,
            sizeof(localInterface)) < 0) {
diff -ru unzip/receiver/src/nwudp.c fixed/receiver/src/nwudp.c
--- unzip/receiver/src/nwudp.c  2021-06-01 06:22:04.000000000 -0400
+++ fixed/receiver/src/nwudp.c  2021-06-01 14:14:02.401213180 -0400
@@ -6,6 +6,7 @@
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>
+
 #include "my_queue.h"
 #include "Globals.h"
 #include "sender.h"
```

Comment: i have edited my code to show create queue area, 

as part of debugging i had made data2 as global and tried printing data from data2 on mains and it works perfectly, so what might be happening?